# count rows for all tables in analysis service tabular (dax)

Tags: dax, tabular

I found a query doing that before but can't find it again. It's something producing

```
table    count
table_A  xxxx
table_B  xxx
table_C  xxx
```

Please help. Thanks-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you saw before, but something like this will produce what you're looking for. Run it against your tabular instance.

```
SELECT CUBE_NAME
    , DIMENSION_CAPTION AS TableName
    , DIMENSION_CARDINALITY AS RowCount
  FROM $system.MDSchema_Dimensions
  ORDER BY DIMENSION_CARDINALITY DESC
```